# How to move similar profession people into newly created object (result) in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have one quick question, I want to move all similar professional people into a newly created object (result), I have written the code but all values are not moved.

```
const data = [
    {
        Name: 'Smith',
        age: 25,
        profession: 'Banker'
    },
    {
        Name: 'Alex',
        age: 28,
        profession: 'IT'
    },
    {
        Name: 'John',
        age: 31,
        profession: 'Banker'
    },
    {
        Name: 'Harry',
        age: 26,
        profession: 'Nurse'
    },
];
const result = {};
```

My code is here ...

```js
const data = [ { Name: "Smith", age: 25, profession: "Banker" }, { Name: "Alex", age: 28, profession: "IT" }, { Name: "John", age: 31, profession: "Banker" }, { Name: "Harry", age: 26, profession: "Nurse" } ];

const result = {};
data.forEach(({ Name, age, profession }) => {
  result[profession] = { Name, age };
});
console.log(result);
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/Sandy4405/pen/wvmLaJX

Comment: Can you share the expected result as well?

Comment: When John comes up, because he's also a Banker, he overwrites Smith. `object[key]` will first create what you expect, but the second time `key` shows up, the previous value is written over. You might want to store all Bankers in an array, i.e. `Array.isArray(result[profession]) ? result[profession].push({ Name, age}) : result[profession] = [{ Name, age}]`

Comment: Check this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/ZExdbeB

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above, the inside of your `forEach` should be:

```js
data.forEach(({ Name, age, profession }) => {
    if (Array.isArray(result[profession])) {
        result[profession].push({ Name, age })
    } else {
        result[profession] = [{ Name, age }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `nested JSON`, which means an array of objects for a similar profession. While iterating, create an array for each profession and use `.push()` to add the objects. The code would look like below

```
data.forEach(({Name,age,profession}) => {
  result[profession] = result[profession] || [];
  result[profession].push({Name,age});
});
```

---

Working Version:

```js
const data = [{
    Name: "Smith",
    age: 25,
    profession: "Banker"
  },
  {
    Name: "Alex",
    age: 28,
    profession: "IT"
  },
  {
    Name: "John",
    age: 31,
    profession: "Banker"
  },
  {
    Name: "Harry",
    age: 26,
    profession: "Nurse"
  }
];
const result = {};
data.forEach(({
  Name,
  age,
  profession
}) => {
  result[profession] = result[profession] || [];
  result[profession].push({
    Name,
    age
  });
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Tushar, for providing the answer, but what does this line means   result[profession] = result[profession] || [];

Comment: In my understanding, it is creating an empty array if the same value does not exist in the given array.

Comment: this is simply a check to create an array for each profession. `result[profession] will have its own value if it exists and if it doesn't exist, it will have an initial value `of the blank array. This will only be the case for the first time. `||` or condition checks and does a fallback if the variable is undefined to prevent errors,

Answer (score 0):

After the first person with a given profession is encountered, each subsequent person with the same profession will overwrite the previous one. You should instead create an array and push each of the people with the same profession to that array.

First, we'll check if the current profession has been encountered before.
If it hasn't, we'll create an empty array to hold all of the people with this profession.

```js
if (!(profession in result)) {
  result[profession] = []
}
```

Then, since the array is now guaranteed to exist for this profession, we can push to our new array the current person. The next time this profession is encountered, our first check will be skipped and we'll just push the next person onto the array.

```js
result[profession].push({
  Name,
  age
})
```

Full example:

```js
const data = [{
  Name: "Smith",
  age: 25,
  profession: "Banker"
}, {
  Name: "Alex",
  age: 28,
  profession: "IT"
}, {
  Name: "John",
  age: 31,
  profession: "Banker"
}, {
  Name: "Harry",
  age: 26,
  profession: "Nurse"
}]

const result = {}

data.forEach(({
  Name,
  age,
  profession
}) => {
  if (!(profession in result))
    result[profession] = []

  result[profession].push({
    Name,
    age
  })
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [`filipe`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10064387/filipe) said in his comment, Your current code is just assigning the values into an object which results in maintaining the single value against keys. To group the same profession values into a respective profession key, You have to do something like this **:**

```js
const data = [ { Name: "Smith", age: 25, profession: "Banker" }, { Name: "Alex", age: 28, profession: "IT" }, { Name: "John", age: 31, profession: "Banker" }, { Name: "Harry", age: 26, profession: "Nurse" } ];

const result = {};
data.forEach(({ Name, age, profession }) => {
  result[profession] ? result[profession].push({ Name, age }) : result[profession] = [{ Name, age }];
});

console.log(result);
```